# Is curvature the exterior covariant derivative of the connection?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature, differentiation, mathematics

Let $P\to M$ be a $G$-principal bundle, $G$ a topological group, $\omega$ the connection and $V$ a vector space.
We define $d_\omega: \Omega^k_G(P, V)\to\Omega^{k+1}_G(P, V)$ the *exterior covariant derivative* such that for a vector-valued differential form $\alpha\in\Omega^k_G(P, V)$, we get $d_\omega\alpha=d\alpha+\omega\wedge_\rho\alpha$, where $\rho:\mathfrak g \to \operatorname{End}(V)$ is a representation of the algebra of $G$.

**Question**: defining the curvature as $\Omega=d\omega+\frac{1}{2}[\omega,\omega]$, is there any representation in which $\Omega=d_\omega\omega$?

**My guess**: no.

The point is that I have found several forums (as well as in [Wikipedia's entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_covariant_derivative)) in which the curvature was expressed as the covariant derivative of the connection, but in the adjoint representation we do not get the $\frac{1}{2}$ in front. Moreover if we notice, we have for matrix groups, $\frac{1}{2}[\omega,\omega]=\omega\wedge\omega$ and thus one might argue that we could get the curvature by using the fundamental representation.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of the exterior covariant derivative isn't $d_\omega\alpha=d\alpha+\omega\wedge_\rho\alpha$.

It is $$ d_\omega\alpha(X...)=d\alpha(\mathrm hX...), $$ where $\mathrm h$ is the horizontal projection.

We then state several things:

- A $k$-form with values in $V$ $\alpha\in\Omega^k(P,V)$ is a *pseudotensorial $k$-form of type $\rho$*, if it is right-equivariant in the sense that $r_g^\ast\alpha=\rho(g^{-1})\alpha$.
- A $k$-form $\alpha$ with values in $V$ is a *tensorial $k$-form of type $\rho$*, if it is a pseudotensorial $k$-form of type $\rho$ and is horizontal in the sense that $\alpha(X_1,...,X_k)=0$ whenever all elements are vertical.
- The covariant exterior derivative of a pseudotensorial form is a tensorial form of one higher degree
- If $\omega$ is the connection form, then it is a pseudotensorial 1-form of type $\text{Ad}$, and we have $d_\omega\omega=\Omega$, so the curvature **is** the covariant exterior derivative.
- If $\alpha$ is a **tensorial** $k$-form of type $\rho$, then we have the "generalized Cartan structure equation" $$ d_\omega\alpha=d\alpha+\omega\wedge_\rho\alpha, $$ however this is valid only if $\alpha$ is a tensorial form, **not** when it is a pseudotensorial one.
- In particular, if $\alpha\in\Omega^k(P,\mathfrak g)$ is a tensorial $k$-form of type $\text{Ad}$, then we have $$ d_\omega\alpha=d\alpha+\omega\wedge_{\text{Ad}}\alpha\equiv d\alpha+[\omega\wedge\alpha], $$ where $[\cdot\wedge\cdot]$ is the Lie-exterior product. One may expand (without using the generalized structure equation) that for the curvature we have $$ \Omega=d\omega+\frac{1}{2}[\omega\wedge\omega], $$ where the anomalous factor of 1/2 comes from the fact that $\omega$ is a *pseudo*tensorial form and thus the generalized structure equation is not valid.

Comment: How do you get the last formula? (When you wrote "one may expand...")

Comment: Btw, I guess that for being horizontal/tensorial you only need to get zero whenever at least one vector is vertical, not all vectors...

Comment: @Wideep Yes it seems you are correct about horizontality. The formula is derived in Kobayashi/Nomizu and "Gauge Theory and Variational Principles" by Bleecker. And in most books that treat connections on principal bundles.

Comment: Thanks, are you sure about KN? Because I could not find the derivation there...

Comment: @Wideep It's page 77, theorem 5.2 in vol 1.

Comment: I'll check that out! Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the case in synthetic differential geometry if we view the connection 1-form $\omega$ on a principal $G$-bundle as a $G$-valued simplicial 1-form. Then the exterior (Darboux) derivative of $\omega$ is indeed the curvature. Theorem 6.7.1 in Anders Kock's [Synthetic Geometry of Manifolds](https://users-math.au.dk/kock/SGM-final.pdf) explains how this relates to the usual curvature formula for classical differential forms.